# Clojure : how do I use use "and" in "reduce"?

Tags: clojure, boolean, reduce

"and" seems to be a macro, so I can't use it in something like `(reduce and list-of-booleans)`

What should I do instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can wrap it into some lambda like this.

```
user=> (reduce (fn [a b] (and a b)) '(true true true))
true
user=> (reduce (fn [a b] (and a b)) '(true true false))
false
```

Of course, you don't need reduce at all, you must use every?:

```
user=> (every? true? '(true false true))
false
```